# is there any way to create unique id's to particular field in django model

Tags: python, django

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    category=models.ForeignKey('Category',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate=models.IntegerField()
    peices=models.IntegerField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here in the product model if  i assign 100 integers to peices  every piece should have a unique id
for eg:
 levis is a product and if i add 100  to the pieces section of this model so that  i could get 100 different unique id's
i tried a lot googling it but its of no use
anykind of help is appreciated

Comment: Hi! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to extract what you are trying to achieve, add some (pseudo)code showing what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In that case I think you need to create additional Piece model with:

```
class Piece(models.Model):

   product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pieces')
```

And remove piece from Product.
You can get all unique pieces from product with:

```
product = Product.objects.get(...) 
pieces = product.pieces.all()
```